# Save image in web server along with text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to post image in web server along with text.  text data saving but image not saving.Then I tried the below code. Now text data also not saving.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage);

NSString *requestString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UserId=%@&CategoryId=%@&Continent=%@&Country=%@&City=%@&Gender=%@&ImageName=%@&ImageData=%@&AgeRange=%@",UserId,CategoryId,continentTextfield.text,countrytextfield.text,citytextfield.text,gender,imagename,imageData,ageTextfield.text];



NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.2.4:98/UserImage.svc/InsertFacialImage?%@",requestString];

//----------------------





NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];

//image

[postbody appendData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]];

[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; file=\"image\"; filename=\"%@.png\"\r\n", imageData]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];



[request setHTTPBody:postbody];
```

//-----------------------

```
NSURLConnection *connReq = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];



if (connReq) {



    NSLog(@"Connection Sucessful");
```

receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

```
}

else {

    NSLog(@"failed");

}

[connReq start];
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors from the server? Are you sure this isn't an issue with the server not properly parsing the POST data?

Comment: server is working fine. Android developers are successfully posted image